# Help with contextual filters needed

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to understand how arguments get passed into a view.

I have a view which **was** working using
content: type (=PersonStory) which is a join table
connecting via Views Relationships to
content: type (=Person)
content: type (=Story)

Here is the old view.
[image]

I have installed Panelizer and have a default page for content: type (=Person). When an author's page is loaded, I want to load a view of stories which they have written.

As you can see from the preview, the NID finds the correct author's name, but none of that author's stories are showing. The NID comes from content: type (=Person) and not from the base table in the view content: type (=PersonStory).

Current view:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contextual filter needed to be linked to Content entity referenced from field_personstory_person_id) Content: Nid and then it worked.

This does not help me understand how to pass the argument from the panel, though ;)